# Parameters missing in $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

Below here, I am trying to send an object in `$state` and retrieving it in `$stateParams`. I think I am doing it correctly and also I have seen many sites and many articles which ask to do so. But I am unable to get it in `$stateParams` in the next Controller.

I know there are many questions over this and I have gone through many. Still I am stuck.
Can someone see where I am wrong?

```
$scope.setup = function (ev, item, parent) {
            console.log("event", ev);
            console.log("item", item);
            console.log("parent in clusters", parent);

            ev.preventDefault();
            if(item!==null){
            var path = parent.id + '.' + item.code;
            path = path.replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase();;
            if (!$(ev.target).closest('a').is('[disabled]')) {
                $rootScope.child = item;
                $rootScope.parent = parent;
                console.log("parent", $rootScope.parent);
                $state.go('setup', {
                    targetYear: $scope.targetYear,
                    path: path
                    //  ,'child': item, 
                    //  'parent': parent 

                });
             }
            }
            else {
                console.log("trade in trade", parent);
                console.log("items from scope", $scope.items);
                var path = parent.name.trim();
                path = path.replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase();
                var totalTradesInOverview = $scope.items;
                console.log("parent", $rootScope.parent);
                $state.go('setup', {
                     targetYear: $scope.targetYear,
                     path: path,
                     params: totalTradesInOverview


                });

            }
        };
```

I think I should get it directly in `$stateParams` in another controller. Am I wrong?

Below is my part of state declaration, if that matters much:

```
 module.config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('setup', {
            url: '/setup/:targetYear/:path',
            views: {
                "main@": {
                    controller: 'TargetsSetupController as model',
                    templateUrl: 'app/targets/setup/setup.tpl.html',
                    // params: params  
                    //I tried even this passing that variable in params like //  params: totalTradesInOverview                                                                             
                },
                "bar@": {
                    controller: 'AController',
                    templateUrl: 'comments.tpl.html'
                }
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what's your console error? also have you got a github repo set up for a full view of your code?

Comment: first make sure. You are setting variable properly while executing $state.go().

Comment: Are you not getting only "params" value or "params","path" and "targetYear" values using $stateParams

Comment: Is the url activating the way you expect? Where are you trying to access the $stateParams?

Comment: I am trying to access $stateParams in the upcoming controller i.e. TargetsSetupController. As for path and targetYear, these two I am getting because as you can see I am appending them to my URL and they are being appended. However once the new state has been loaded, I am expecting to retrieve 'totalTradesInOverview' variable from $stateParams in new controller. Alas! There it says undefined

Comment: Tried as suggested by DzinX below. Still this gives me undefined `console.log("reading params here", $stateParams.params);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only parameters explicitly expected by the state are accessible through `$stateParams`.

In your example, your `"setup"` state declaration has the following URL: `'/setup/:targetYear/:path'`, which means it expects `targetYear` and `path` parameters.

You're trying to pass a third parameter (`params`) and it's not visible, because it's not expected.

To pass the third parameter, you can declare it in a special `params` object in your state declaration, with some default value (note the naming clash -- maybe that's the source of your confusion?):

```
$stateProvider.state('setup', {
    url: '/setup/:targetYear/:path',
    views: {...},
    params: {
        params: []
    }
});
```

Now the `params` parameter should be visible in $stateParams.

If I were you, I would rename `params` to `totalTradesInOverview` both in the above state declaration and in your `$state.go` statement, to avoid confusion.

Also see [$stateProvider.state documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state) for more options you can apply to passed parameters.

Comment: You are indicating to pass a param object in state definition. But I want to pass it through controller in $state.go(). I get this object in the mid of my controller somewhere and then I have to pass it to next controller.
How are you suggesting to keep it in state definition already. I think I didn't follow you. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: First, just change your state definition to the one I provided (I omitted the views part) and check if it works. If it does, I'll try to explain more.

Comment: Also, from your comment under the question I can see you expect the parameter to be actually called `totalTradesInOverview`. Then, you should name it so in the state (`params: {totalTradesInOverview: []}`) and in your state.go: `$state.go('setup', {targetYear: $scope.targetYear, path: path, totalTradesInOverview: totalTradesInOverview})`

Comment: I modified the state definition as per yours. Now how am I suppose to pass my object from $state.go()
Currently i have changed it to:
`$state.go('targets.targets-setup', {
                     targetYear: $scope.targetYear,
                     path: path,
                     params: totalTradesInOverview
                     

                });`

Comment: If you defined `params: {params: []}` in $stateProvider.state, then call `$state.go('setup', {targetYear: $scope.targetYear, path: path, params: totalTradesInOverview}` (exactly as you were doing in your original post) and read `$stateParams.params` in your next controller.

Comment: So basically, what I get from you is that define a param object in state and then pass a param object from state.go(). The passed object will replace the defined object. Is this understanding correct.
Also if it is correct, should the defined array in state definition contain a params array always